# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo me muestre 5 registros en mi consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/

include ('conexionb.php');
class Usuarios extends DataBase
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function buscar($usuario){
        $datos;
        $sth = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE "%'.$usuario.'%" ');

        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
           $datos[] = array("value" => $value['nombre'], "idPersona" => $value['idPErsona']);
        }
        return $datos;
    }
}

 ?>
```

No sé como hacer que solo me muestre 5 registros al consultar la base de datos

Comment: `SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE "%' .$ususario.'% LIMIT 5"`...algo así

Comment: añade tu código como texto

Comment: ya lo puse el codigo como texto

Comment: tambien ya puse el LIMIT asi como en la primera respuesta pero no funciona y me manda error de sintaxis

Comment: el error de sintaxis ahora es por tu uso incorrecto de las comillas simples y dobles....el texto concatenado debe ser `LIKE '%Nombre_del_Usuario%' LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si tu consulta va bien y te extrae los datos, solo debes agregar un "LIMIT 5" al final de tu select, a manera que se vea algo asi...

```
"%'.$usuario.'%" LIMIT 5 ');
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 3):

Por medio de [`LIMIT`](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-limit.html):

```
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE ? LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la palabra reservada `LIMIT`, después de esta agregas la cantidad de registros que quieres mostrar

`SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE %''% LIMIT 5`

Con eso limitas la cantidad de registros que traes de base de datos,

Prueba e indica si funciona.